# How to train a linear regression if the number of sample features is variable (time series) (in sklearn)

Tags: regression, time-series, scikit-learn

Let's assume for the samples $\{(x_i,y_i)\},$ the $dim\ x_i$ is variable, e.g. a time series $x_i = (x_{i1},\cdot,x_{iT_i}).$ Then how do we train a linear regression for such samples? Especially how do we deal with such case in `sklearn`?

Currently I naively fixed a length $l$ (usually the maximal length of $x_i$ in samples), then add $0$ for the length of sample being short than $l;$ or cut off for the length of sample being longer than $l$ (test sample).

Since I never used the deep learning library, do you have any example for the code of `LSTM`？ I think such input samples must be very common in LSTM.

Another way I think is interpolate/extrapolate each time series (sample) to get a continuous curve. Then fix some common synthetic time points to obtain  a synthetic time series for each sample. Then the training is based on those  synthetic time series with same length.

**Update:**

If we train a time series prediction (no label) like ARMA, then it is easy to use a moving window to obtain the equal length data. However if it is a Supervised learning, The samples are something like:

$$\{(x_1^1,x_1^2,x_1^3),y_1\},\{(x_2^1,x_2^2),y_2\},\{(x_3^1,x_3^2,x_3^3,x_3^4,),y_3\},\cdots$$

Then even for RNN or LSTM, how to deal with it? It seems Keras also demands the equal length on $x.$

Comment: Maybe compute some features from the time series? For a better answer you need to give some context, what does the outcome $y_i$ measure?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen for example, $y_i$ is a float number to measure the intensity of time series curve.

Comment: Yes, I think in vanilla linear regression, you do need fixed-length inputs, so unless you calculate a  set of summary features, yeah, you might be stuck. LSTM is an alternative but it seems super heavyweight -- you could do sequence regression with it though. Keras is pretty friendly with a small learning curve; [here's a tutorial for sequence _classification_](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), which you can adapt to regression by changing the objective function.

Comment: @tchainzzz pls see my update, actually is there any reference specific to introduce this part of Machine learning?